# Validação numeric(12,2) Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou com o seguinte questão, tenho um campo no banco Postgresql do tipo numeric(12,2) ao enviar um valor de um form não encontrei uma forma de validar o valor no PHP para inserir no banco esse valor.

Erro gerado: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERRO: estouro de campo numeric DETAIL: Um campo com precisão 12, escala 2 deve arredondar para um valor absoluto menor do que 10^10.

Comment: São valores que vem para integração. São valores de NFs, queria algo pra validar esses valores para não estourar no banco.

Comment: vc pode alterar o tipo do campo? qunado vc diz valores de NF está falando sobre dinheiro certo?

Comment: Não posso alterar o tipo temos muitos valores cadastrados e outros pontos que fazer cadastro nessa tabela. Sim dinheiro.

Comment: Isso serve de alguma ajuda? `<?php
define('LIMITE', 10000000000);
$valor = 90000000000;
if($valor > LIMITE ){
 echo 'vai estoura o limite';
}`

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado @rray !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser saber se o valor informado é maior que o limite da coluna, pegue a dica do erro, faça 10 elevado a 10(`10^10`), jogue em uma variável ou constante e faça as comparações.

```
<?php
   define('LIMITE', 9999999999.99);
   $valor = 90000000000;
   if($valor > LIMITE ){
      echo 'vai estoura o limite';
  }
```

Comment: @MarcosRegis aponta o erro ai, fiz a conta errado? posso corrigir ou apagar se não tiver salvação.

Comment: @MarcosRegis muito obrigado pela correção! :D

Answer (score 3):

Um erro muito comum quando se trabalha com o tipo `numeric(precisão, escala)` é achar que **precisão** indica quantos digitos vai caber na parte inteira.

Na verdade, **precisão** vai indicar quantos digitos o número inteiro vai ter, incluindo as casas decimais.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
SELECT CAST(123456 AS NUMERIC(6, 4))
```

Vai estourar o campo pois ele será interpretado da como sendo 123456.0000

Então, para o tipo do exemplo, o maior valor que caberá no campo é 99.9999

Até mesmo o valor 99.99999 não será aceito, pois ele acabará sendo arredondado para 100.0000 
Já o valor 99.99994 será aceito, pois ele será arredondado para 99.9999

Para saber qual o maior valor aceito por um campo NUMERIC faça `((10 ^ precisão)/(10 ^ escala)) - (1/(10^escala))`

Exemplo usando `NUMERIC(3, 3)`

```
((10 ^ 3)/(10 ^ 3)) - (1/(10 ^ 3))
(1000/1000) - (1/1000)
1 - 0.001
0.999
```

Esta é uma das situações que aprendi no dia a dia, pois nem mesmo no manual informa a formula de se saber qual o maior valor de um campo.

> Nota: Não é possível ter campo com precisão menor que a escala