# Sql - postgres - Precisão arbitraria ::numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql

Como funciona a precisão arbitraria ao definir a coluna como `numeric`?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92588/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-numeric12-2-postgres/92655#92655

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo manual do Postgres podemos ver que o numeric tem precisão de:

> 131072 digitos antes do ponto decimal
>   16383 digitos depois do ponto decimal

Este é o valor default, contudo é possivel definir este padrão com :

```
numeric(num1, num2)
```

Na qual `num1` é a precisão, ou seja quantos digitos eu quero que tenha meu numeric.
E `num2` é quantos decimais ele deve ter.

Deve-se salientar que `num2` utiliza da definicão de `num1` ou seja, não é uma soma 
de algarismos, é a utilizacão dele, exemplo:

```
EX1 : numeric(12,2) // estou dizendo que terei 12 digitos, sendo 2 decimais.
EX2 : numeric(8,6)  // estou dizendo que terei 8 digitos, sendo 6 decimais.
```

Nesta situação meu `EX1` comporta `9.999.999.999,99`.
Enquanto `EX2` não consegue passar de `99,999999`; pois eu defini um total de 8 digitos sendo 6 decimais.

#### Analogia

subtraindo `num2` de `num1` teremos a quantidade de decimais suportados em nossa coluna.